# Why isn't current carried through a vacuum?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, vacuum

The empty vacuum of space shouldn't offer any resistance to a travelling electron, and so a large collection of electrons should similarly travel through a vacuum without resistance.

As a result, the bottom line is that an empty vacuum should be an excellent conductor of electricity, since it offers no resistance.

And in fact, this is exactly what a Free-electron laser does:

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser#Large_facilities_required) is a Wikipedia article on the subject.

Now, I understand this is expensive gear, but presumably someone could come up with a cheaper version that could offer charges pumped through a difference in potential.

There's another post here, the answers to which, frankly, don't seem to be very useful and claim that empty space isn't a good conductor - that's just not correct, since a **free electron laser** is a real thing that exists, and does exactly what they said it couldn't, which is pump high voltage.

I found a similar SE post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178831/).

Does anyone know if there's a cheap consumer version that pumps charge through a vacuum?

Comment: any old vacuum tube triode...

Comment: Yes, evidently old-style electronics has been forgotten. And even CRT displays.

Comment: @hyportnex vacuum tube diode is a better example.

Comment: @verdelite true but will be more difficult to find one

Comment: FWIW, [J.J. Thomson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Thomson), [Cathode ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray)

Comment: @hyportnex, given your mention of the vacuum tube triode above, I can't resist linking to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzyXMEpq4qw) that I first watched quite a few years ago, and that I have enjoyed watching several times since.

Comment: @Alfred_Centauri Thank you, that was amazing; M. Paillard is a true artist of *our* profession, oh how I envy him!

Comment: @hyportnex I might have some hiding away somewhere.

Comment: Note that the electrons in a free electron laser are the medium, it's not producing a beam of electrons. But regardless, think about what happens if you let an electron leave a wire in a vacuum - for one, it takes quite a bit of effort, and two, it will attract the electron back towards the wire (which now has a positive charge). So to get electrons to flow in a vacuum, you need to give it enough of a kick to cross the gap without returning back to where it started. That's why it's an electric isolant - it's a relative measure; it's easier to pass electrons through copper wires or even air.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I figured I wasn't the first person to think of this. In particular, using a vacuum filled with free electrons, or a charged gas, seems like a good way to implement Faraday induction, since there's no resistance in that case.

Answer (score 28):

As you noted, particle accelerators are examples of electric currents flowing though a vacuum. In order to answer why a vacuum is considered an insulator, you have to consider where the charged particles come from. Consider the space between the plates of a capacitor that is connected to a battery. Even though there is a voltage difference between the plates, the electrons cannot cross the gap because they are too tightly bonded to the atoms in the plates. It takes a very high voltage for the electrons to be torn away from the atoms in the plates. Once this happens (or the electrons are helped by [incoming photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect)), then the electrons can be accelerated through the vacuum by the electric field between the plates.

A vacuum is an insulator because of the work you have to do to put mobile electric charges into it. A conductor like a copper wire already has mobile electrons, so it takes very little work to get them moving in a current.

Answer (score 13):

It is perfectly possible for current to flow through vacuum: it is just not a conduction current but instead a [*convection* current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359585/difference-between-conduction-current-density-convection-current-density).  Quoting [this page:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Conduction_mechanisms_in_various_media)

> ... any stream of charged objects (ions, for example) may constitute an electric current.

For instance ions travelling in an accelerator (usually under vacuum or near vacuum) create a current which experimentalists measure in Amps (or fractions thereof).

Comment: Are CRTs so old we’ve forgotten about them? Sigh. I’m officially old now.

Comment: @Jon Custer i was thinking the exact same thing before seeing your comment